# Cross-platform File Browser for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to select an image from my local system that is external to the Unity project. This could be on a computer, IOS, android, etc. What is the best strategy to allow a user to open an external image and load it during runtime?

Comment: In the asset store you can search for file browser, there are some free ones

Comment: None of the assets document iOS compatibilty. Some mention MacOS only. If there was an asset out there, I would love to use it. Otherwise, I may need to build a NativePlugin myself.

Comment: What were the specific plugins that you tried that didn't work? When i did a brief search I found several, albeit not all of them were free. Of the free ones which ones did you try in a sample project?

Comment: Can you provide some of the free ones you've looked at that support IOS? I've not yet found any. I'm looking at documentation of all of the asset store plugins and none mention explicit support of IOS, only MacOS.